# Anchor tags stuck inside their container?

Tags: html, hyperlink, broken-links

I have an index that link to sections throughout the page but for some reason all of them will only take me to the top of container that contains the sections. See the code below (all of the sections are made up of the same section code (minus section container) listed below but with different schools):

```
<!-- Outter container -->
  <div class="container chapter">

<!--Section Index-->
    <div class="container chapters-index">
      <a href="#school-id">School</a> |    
 </div>

<!-- Section container (this is where the anchors link to)-->
    <div class="container chapters">

<!-- Section to be linked to -->
        <div id="school-id">
          <div class="col-md-5 chapters">
            <img src="images/chapters/school-logo.jpg" class="school responsive">
            <h6>Meets weekly on Wednesday after school, <strong>3:30pm-6pm</strong>.</h6>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod suscipit gravida. Donec non magna pretium, commodo nisl nec, sollicitudin enim. Phasellus lobortis lectus a urna auctor maximus. Donec nibh metus, finibus et rhoncus ut,
              aliquam sit amet mauris. Sed odio libero, pretium nec placerat ac, commodo quis mi. Integer aliquam mauris lacus, at finibus nibh fringilla id. Ut congue sit amet tortor nec laoreet. Duis posuere finibus nisi, sed fermentum sapien. Curabitur
              porta interdum elit, nec ultrices neque aliquet at. Vivamus eleifend est sit amet hendrerit vehicula. Nulla malesuada metus eget luctus consequat.</p>

          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I've been trying to figure out the issue all night! Am I missing something here? Why are my links not going to their appointed anchors?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a JS Fiddle? Your coding looks correct. I'm going to suspect this is partly to CSS, you may need to add some padding to create spacing above your anchor.

Comment: @Lee http://jsfiddle.net/tze3uhrL/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work okay for me in the JSFiddle you linked.

My diagram below shows the boundaries of the `school-id` div, is this correct? The image is part of the school div, and not the categories at the top?

The image is appearing at the top of the anchor, which I believe is correct?

http://jsfiddle.net/tze3uhrL/1/

[image]

Comment: There's much more code than this. I didn't paste it all because of NDA. That section piece is multiplied by about 12 (all with their own unique id's of course). There's plenty of room on the page.
What's even more annoying is I'd added a fixed "back to the top" feature (after this issue had already been established, mind you) since there is so much content and it works just fine.

Comment: It might be easier if you can give us a better representation of your page, maybe replace the text with placeholder text if that's an issue? But something that can show a more accurate display of styling and other elements that are on the page.

Comment: It's the darndest thing! I copied/pasted the exact code from my file to a jsfiddle and it worked properly! Of course it doesn't work properly outside of JDfiddle but does that mean anything? Something in the <head>?

Comment: Yes, it means something else on your site is affecting it. It's going to be very hard to identify what without being able to see it.